# What happens after a MemoryError is raised

Tags: python, memory

I might have the issue of memory overflow in a client where it loads a possibly huge amount of data from a database. An example in python3:

```py
try:
   # returns a list
   storage = get_bigdata(id)
except MemoryError as e:
   storage.clear()
   log(e)
```

The question is that I don't know what happens after the exception is raised. Does the list contain something? How should I proceed?

Suggestions about how to better handle this problem is appreciated, but I am mostly interested in how the computer and program handles this after an exception is raised in this case. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't the code (`storage.clear()`) raise a *NameError*?

Comment: Why should it? I am not sure if it is even needed if the list does not contain anything. I don't know the behaviour of the program after the exception.

Comment: After a memory error there is not much you can reliably do to recover. There may not be enough memory to process all of your `except` clause. The docs say: Because of the underlying memory management architecture (C’s malloc() function), the interpreter may not always be able to completely recover from this situation; it nevertheless raises an exception so that a stack traceback can be printed, in case a run-away program was the cause.

Comment: If the call to `get_bigdata()` fails with a memory error, then the assignment to `storage` never takes place, and so you will get a `NameError`, unless of course `storage` already had a value (in which case you will get an `AttributeError`) or was previously defined but not assigned (in which case you will get  an `UnboundLocal` error).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Not sure how I make it an accepted answer?